# How to fix this: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (installer)

Tags: maven, javafx

I've been trying to run the code `mvn clean install` but this error shows up:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (installer) on project cloudstaff.communicator: Command execution failed.: Cannot run program "javapackager" (in directory "/home/users/matthewb/Workbench/workbench"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more when this error happened. Did you use a starter template or something?

Comment: I have another codebase where i am using this code in terminal                           
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/users/matthewb/Workbench/launcher/target/fxlauncher-1.0.14-jar-with-dependencies.jar -DgroupId=com.cloudstaff.workbench -DartifactId=fxlauncher -Dversion=1.0.14 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true                                                  then in my other codebase i want to mvn clean in stall but this error shows up                 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (installer) on project